# Any mistakes or improvements to my use case diagram

Tags: uml, actor, use-case

Here's the question:

CarHere is a national car rental company that provides low cost car rental extensively in the British Isles.  Their cars are available through their rental offices located at all main airports and some central city locations.  They currently have a poorly performing computerised system that is to be replaced.  A team has now been commissioned to start the development work.

When a potential customer requests a rental from CarHere company the booking clerk takes the rental requirements that include the pick-up and drop-off times and places, the class of vehicle and any special needs.  A booking will be made once the details are agreed.  All bookings are provisional until confirmed by the customer before the given confirmation date
.
For each booking, the booking clerk will record the details of the customer and any other drivers they nominate: title, first name, surname, telephone, address, licence number and class of car to be rented and any special features.  Once the customer pays the full amount the clerk will record the payment details: payment date, payment method and amount.  The clerk then updates the bookings as “confirmed” and issues a rental document to be signed by the customer.  Payments can be made by credit/debit card or in cash.  Confirmed bookings may be cancelled no later than three days prior to pick-up; the payment is reimbursed, less a charge of 10%.

Every morning a list of provisional bookings that are overdue and a list of all cancellations for confirmed bookings are produced.  Provisional bookings are then cancelled and customer is reimbursed.

Here's my diagram:

[image]

Is there anything I can do to improve the diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you want to understand that included use cases are required and extensions are optional.  "Add payment record" doesn't look optional, and neither do the extensions to "Get rental requirements."  So, if you're not clear on this, you'll want to revise your extends and includes accordingly.

Next, don't try to fully explain the behavior of a use case in terms of other use cases it includes.  If your included use cases are really part of the base use case, then leave them out. There are other ways of documenting the behavior as I will explain.

Next, if you have different ways of accepting payment, you might want to have each as a separate use case that inherits the "Pay" use case.

Finally, to fully explain the behavior of a use case, use an activity diagram, one per use case.  You can go into whatever detail you want there.  You may also want to google "use case narrative" to see ways that you can verbally document the behavior of a use case; this narrative is what an activity diagram would depict.  If you have a particularly complex path through a use case, look up "use case scenario" and how to document one with a sequence diagram.